# Kinematics Problem requiring Calculus

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, integration, calculus

Let the Instantaneous Velocity of a rocket  just after launching be given by

v={ 3t               for     0<=    t <2

2t+ 3t^2     for    2<=  t<=3

t^3              for t>3

Find the distance travelled by the rocket during t=0 to t =5s.

How do I Integrate when the definition is different for different region? 
Note : I have just started Calculus.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Do take a moment to read our [advice on what is on-topic and off-topic here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and our [policy on homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Comment: Alright I will take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should integrate velocity with respect to time separately for the intervals 0-2,2-3 and 3-5 seconds to get the displacements in these intervals. Then sum up the displacements to get the net displacement.

Comment: Are you giving JEE ?

Comment: Yes but in 2021

Comment: Good luck from my end